# Twig variable scope -- global only available inside loop

Tags: scope, twig, drupal-8

I have an object variable which only contains data when accessed from *inside* a `for x in y` loop.

This is happening within a field template for a Drupal 8 theme, where the goal is to access a sibling field's value.

Simplified snippet:

```
{% for x in [1] %}
  Inside loop = {{ _parent.element['#object'].get('field_section_theme').value }}
{% endfor %}

Outside loop = {{ _parent.element['#object'].get('field_section_theme').value }}
```

Output:

```
Inside loop = normal
Outside loop =
```

I'd understand if a variable that was *set* within a loop was unavailable outside it, but this is unrelated, taken from the `_context` of the template itself.

My workaround of wrapping a reference to the variable in a simple one-time `for` loop has solved my immediate issue, but I'd love to understand what's happening here!

(I'd also prefer a cleaner way than the `for x in [1]` approach, but normally if you only want something executed once you just write it out!)

Comment: Does not make any sense. You should provide some extra code to figure out the real issue here

Comment: It makes no sense at all, hence the question :)

It's a field template for a Drupal 8 theme -- this code accesses the value set in a sibling field (`field_section_theme`).

There's no *code* context to provide as those lines, in isolation, reproduce the strangeness. (I came across it at the very start of creating the template.)

Comment: not all variables available to a page are available in every template. It depends on which template you are using and should be shown in comments at the top of the template.

Comment: @garek007 This is within the same template, with the value available inside the loop, but not available outside of it. I've stripped literally everything else from the twig file other than the listed lines and the strangeness persists.

Comment: could you do a `{{ dump(_context) }}` or `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}` ?

Comment: @DarkBee Fresh eyes revealed that `_parent` is specific to a loop's context (and in this case was set to the template's `_context`), so outside of the loop I just needed to drop it from the access path. (Details in my answer below.)

Answer (score 2):

This was a scoping error, based on my misunderstanding of how and where `_parent` was defined -- I assumed it was provided by Drupal, where logically the "parent" of the field I'm currently rendering is the node entity, which in turn contains the other field I'm trying to reference.

**However**, `_parent` seems to be a twig construct, with `_parent` *within* the loop referring to the template's main scope, while `_parent` *outside* the loop makes no sense.

It's pretty obvious in hindsight, but since my code started life within a loop and the **self > parent > sibling** path I was using made sense (in a Drupal context) I couldn't understand why the variable was unavailable outside the loop.

I can't find much useful documentation on `_parent` at all, so any links would be appreciated.

---

Fixing my particular issue was as simple as removing `_parent` from the "outside loop" access path, i.e. changing

`Outside loop = {{ _parent.element['#object'].get('field_section_theme').value }}`

to

`Outside loop = {{ element['#object'].get('field_section_theme').value }}`

Comment: One to remember :)